# Help with matrix derivative

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

In my studies of applied mathematics, specifically optimization and applied linear algebra, I have come across the following expression which I need help differentiating:

> $ z(B,C) = \lVert Y-B \phi(CX) \rVert_F ^2 = \text{trace} \left( (Y-B \phi(CX))(Y-B \phi(CX))^T \right) $

where $ Y \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times s},X\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times s}  $ are two constant real matrices, $ B \in \mathbb{R} ^{m\times k} $ and $ C\in\mathbb{R}^{k \times n} $ are the two variable matrices of the function $ z(B,C) $ defined above, $ \lVert \bullet \rVert_F $ is the Frobenius norm and all matrix dimensions involved are constant and non-variable.

The function $ \phi : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ is a nonlinear function defined for real numbers as follows:

> $ \phi(x) = \left\{
> \begin{array}{ll}
>       0 & x \leq 0 \\
>       x & x > 0 \\
> \end{array} 
> \right. $

and we extend its definition to matrices element-wise, that is $ (\phi(A))_{i,j} = \phi((A)_{i,j}) $.

I would like to find the matrix derivative of the function $ z $, as stated above, with respect to $ C $, that is $ \frac{\partial z}{\partial C}$.

Differentiating with respect to $ B $ is easy enough as $ C $ doesn't impede applying standard formulas, but my problem is with differentiating with respect to $ C $ as it is the argument of a nonlinear function and I do not know how to derive it with respect to matrices.

I was hoping someone could please come to the rescue and help me differentiate the function $ z $ with respect to $ C $. I thank all helpers.

Comment: In the first derivative, is A supposed to be C?

Comment: Does this book have copy right? This not allowed on this website

Comment: @JohnPolcari : yes fixed it now

Comment: @CloudJR : no, it is OK

Comment: @JohnPolcari : thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's use a convention where uppercase Latin letters represent matrices, lowercase Latin vectors, and Greek letters are scalars.

The function you've denoted by $\phi$ is the [ReLU function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_%28neural_networks%29), $r(\alpha)$, whose derivative is the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function)
$$h(\alpha) = \frac{dr(\alpha)}{d\alpha} \implies dr = h\,d\alpha$$
Applying these scalar functions element-wise on a matrix argument $A=CX,$  produces matrix results, which we'll denote as
$$\eqalign{
 R &= r(A) \cr
 H &= h(A) \implies dR = H\odot dA = H\odot(dC\,X) \cr
}$$
where $\odot$ is the elementwise/Hadamard product.

Define a new matrix variable
$$M=BR-Y \implies dM = B\,dR + dB\,R$$ 
Write the function in terms of this new variable, then find its differential.
$$\eqalign{
\lambda &= \|M\|^2_F = M:M \cr
d\lambda &= 2M:dM \cr
 &= 2M:B\,dR + 2M:dB\,R \cr
 &= 2B^TM:dR + 2MR^T:dB \cr
 &= 2B^TM:H\odot(dC\,X) + 2MR^T:dB \cr
 &= 2(B^TM)\odot H:(dC\,X) + 2MR^T:dB \cr
 &= 2((B^TM)\odot H)X^T:dC + 2MR^T:dB \cr
}$$
Setting $dB=0$ yields the gradient wrt $C$
$$\frac{\partial\lambda}{\partial C} = 2((B^TM)\odot H)X^T$$
And setting $dC=0$ yields the gradient wrt $B$
$$\frac{\partial\lambda}{\partial B} = 2MR^T$$

**NB:** Depending on your preferred [layout convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Layout_conventions), you may need to transpose these results.

Also, the colon notation used above (called the Frobenius product) is just a convenient way of writing the trace function, i.e. $\,\,A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB)$.

The cyclic property of the trace leads to several ways to rearrange the terms in a Frobenius product. For example, all of the following expressions are equivalent
$$\eqalign{
 A:BC
 &= A^T:(BC)^T \cr
 &= BC:A \cr
 &= AC^T:B \cr
 &= B^TA:C \cr
}$$

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the name of $ \phi $ as I was not aware of this.

Comment: Thanks for your masterpiece answer, I appreciate it.